# Linux - Debian Tinker Asus S R2.0 board

Tags: networkmanager, nmcli, wifi-hotspot

Kernel 4.4.194
Configured as ap. Ap comes up, is available but unreliable

- Android table connects perfectly
- iPad, iPhone and Mac cannot connect
  When android connects:

```
Sep 19 21:52:56 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: ============ STA [2a:56:6b:23:e7:64]  ===================
Sep 19 21:52:56 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: mac_id : 2
Sep 19 21:52:56 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: wireless_mode : 0x0b
Sep 19 21:52:56 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: mimo_type : 0
Sep 19 21:52:56 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: static smps : N
Sep 19 21:52:56 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: bw_mode : 20MHz, ra_bw_mode : 20MHz
Sep 19 21:52:56 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: rate_id : 3
Sep 19 21:52:56 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: rssi : -1 (%), rssi_level : 0
Sep 19 21:52:56 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: is_support_sgi : Y, is_vht_enable : N
Sep 19 21:52:56 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: disable_ra : N, disable_pt : N
Sep 19 21:52:56 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: is_noisy : N
Sep 19 21:52:56 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: txrx_state : 0
Sep 19 21:52:56 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: curr_tx_rate : CCK_1M (L)
Sep 19 21:52:56 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: curr_tx_bw : 20MHz
Sep 19 21:52:56 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: curr_retry_ratio : 0
Sep 19 21:52:56 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: ra_mask : 0x00000000000fffff
Sep 19 21:52:56 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: send eapol packet 1/4
Sep 19 21:52:56 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: recv eapol packet 2/4
Sep 19 21:52:56 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: send eapol packet 3/4
Sep 19 21:52:56 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: recv eapol packet 4/4
Sep 19 21:52:56 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: set pairwise key camid:1, addr:2a:56:6b:23:e7:64, kid:0, type:AES
```

when other devices fail

```
Sep 19 21:08:38 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: ============ STA [16:49:69:2f:f9:2b]  ===================
Sep 19 21:08:38 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: mac_id : 2
Sep 19 21:08:38 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: wireless_mode : 0x0b
Sep 19 21:08:38 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: mimo_type : 0
Sep 19 21:08:38 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: static smps : N
Sep 19 21:08:38 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: bw_mode : 20MHz, ra_bw_mode : 20MHz
Sep 19 21:08:38 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: rate_id : 3
Sep 19 21:08:38 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: rssi : -1 (%), rssi_level : 0
Sep 19 21:08:38 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: is_support_sgi : Y, is_vht_enable : N
Sep 19 21:08:38 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: disable_ra : N, disable_pt : N
Sep 19 21:08:38 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: is_noisy : N
Sep 19 21:08:38 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: txrx_state : 0
Sep 19 21:08:38 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: curr_tx_rate : CCK_1M (L)
Sep 19 21:08:38 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: curr_tx_bw : 20MHz
Sep 19 21:08:38 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: curr_retry_ratio : 0
Sep 19 21:08:38 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: ra_mask : 0x00000000000fffff
Sep 19 21:08:38 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: send eapol packet 1/4
Sep 19 21:08:38 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: recv eapol packet 2/4
Sep 19 21:08:38 OEI-XXXX kernel: NOHZ: local_softirq_pending 08
Sep 19 21:08:38 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: send eapol packet 3/4
Sep 19 21:08:38 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: recv eapol packet 4/4
Sep 19 21:08:38 OEI-XXXX kernel: NOHZ: local_softirq_pending 08
Sep 19 21:08:38 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: set pairwise key camid:1, addr:16:49:69:2f:f9:2b, kid:0, type:AES
Sep 19 21:08:39 OEI-XXXX kernel: NOHZ: local_softirq_pending 08
Sep 19 21:08:41 OEI-XXXX kernel: NOHZ: local_softirq_pending 08
Sep 19 21:08:54 OEI-XXXX kernel: RTW: clear key for addr:16:49:69:2f:f9:2b, camid:1
```

I am totally lost. Cannot even understand where do I need to look,
By the way, a similar setup, configuration on a Raspberry PI (Ubuntu) works every time and very reliable.
Any help will be appreciated. - Thanks,